# Java Hibernate application using mySQL- Login page does not work

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

I am working on a hibernate project using apache.tomcat in netbeans in which I am creating an application with a user login (employee ID and password) that allows baseball field employees (from mysql database) to request passes to use the field. Users should be able to 1) choose an event for reservation (date & time) from a drop down menu, 2) input their group size, group name, and employee department(drop-down) and 3) manage the reservations on file specific to their employee ID.

I can access the login screen, but nothing happens when I enter employee credentials. I am not sent to the memberscreen.jsp upon entering a correct login, and I do not get the errors I set up for invalid logins. I have been at this for hours and I can not seem to find where I went wrong.

Note: The project requires that I use hibernate

I have tried googling ways to fix this but I have come up short, I think my problem may be too specific. I am getting no errors and the build is successful, but not functional.

1. logonservlet.java

   ```
   package servlets;
   import business.Employee;
   import business.EmployeeDB;
   import java.io.IOException;
   import java.io.PrintWriter;
   import java.util.List;
   import javax.servlet.RequestDispatcher;
   import javax.servlet.ServletException;
   import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
   import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
   import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

   public class LogonServlet extends HttpServlet {
   protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
   throws ServletException, IOException {
   response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
   String msg = "", empid = "";
   long pattempt;
   String URL = "/Logon.jsp";
   Employee e;

   try {
       empid = request.getParameter("empid").trim();
       e = EmployeeDB.getEmployee(empid);
       if (e == null) {
           msg = "No member record found<br>";
       } else {
           pattempt = Long.parseLong(request.getParameter("password"));
           e.setPassattempt((int) pattempt);
           if (!e.isAuthenticated()) {
               msg = "Member found but not authenticated<br>";
           } else {
               msg = "member authenticated<br>";
               URL = "/MemberScreen.jsp";
           }
           request.getSession().setAttribute("e", e);
       }
   } catch (Exception x) {
       msg = "Servlet exception: " + x.getMessage();
   }

   request.setAttribute("msg", msg);
   RequestDispatcher disp =
           getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher(URL);
   disp.forward(request,response);

   }
   // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="HttpServlet methods. 
   Click on the + sign on the left to edit the code.">
       /**
        * Handles the HTTP <code>GET</code> method.
        *
        * @param request servlet request
        * @param response servlet response
        * @throws ServletException if a servlet-specific error occurs
        * @throws IOException if an I/O error occurs
        */
       @Override
       protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse         
    response)
               throws ServletException, IOException {
           processRequest(request, response);
       }

       /**
        * Handles the HTTP <code>POST</code> method.
        *
        * @param request servlet request
        * @param response servlet response
        * @throws ServletException if a servlet-specific error occurs
        * @throws IOException if an I/O error occurs
        */
       @Override
       protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request,                 
    HttpServletResponse response)
               throws ServletException, IOException {
           processRequest(request, response);
       }

       /**
        * Returns a short description of the servlet.
        *
        * @return a String containing servlet description
       */
       @Override
       public String getServletInfo() {
           return "Short description";
       }// </editor-fold>

   }
   ```
2. Logon.jsp

   ```
   <%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
   <!DOCTYPE html >

   <html>
        <head>
           <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
           <title>Field Pass</title>
       </head>
       <body>
           <h1>Welcome</h1> 
           <p>Please Enter your id and password:</p>
           <form action="Logon" method="post">
               <table>
                   <tr>
                       <td>User ID:</td>
                       <td><input type="text" name="userid" id="userid"
                            value="${empty user.userID ? cookie.memid.value : user.userID }" />
                       </td>           
                   </tr>
                   <tr>
                       <td>Password:</td>
                       <td><input type="password" name="password" id="password">
                       </td>
                   </tr>
               </table>
               <br>        
               <input type="submit" value="Log in">
           </form>
           <br>
       </body>
   </html>
   ```
3. employee.java

   ```
   package business;

   import java.util.Date;
   import javax.persistence.Column;
   import javax.persistence.Entity;
   import javax.persistence.Id;
   import javax.persistence.Table;
   import javax.persistence.Temporal;
   import javax.persistence.Transient;
   import org.hibernate.annotations.NamedQuery;

   @Entity
   @Table(name="Employee")
   @NamedQuery(name="dbget_Employee", query="from EMPLOYEE where EMP_ID = :EMP_ID")
   public class Employee {

       public String getMsg() {
           return msg;
       }

       public void setMsg(String msg) {
           this.msg = msg;
       }

       @Id
       @Column(name="EMP_ID")
       private int emp_id;

       @Column(name="LAST_NAME")
       private String last_name;

       @Column(name="FIRST_NAME")
       private String first_name;

       @Column(name="MIDDLE_INITIAL")
       private String middle_initial;

       @Column(name="HIRE_DATE")
       @Temporal(javax.persistence.TemporalType.DATE)
       private Date hire_date;

       @Column(name="DEPT_ID")
       private int dept_id;

       @Column(name="PASSWORD")
       private int password;

       @Column(name="ADMIN")
       private String admin;

       @Transient
       private int passattempt;

       @Transient
       private String msg;

        public Employee() {
           emp_id = 0;
           last_name= "";
           first_name = "";
           middle_initial = "";
           hire_date = null;
           dept_id = 0;
           password = 0;
           admin = "";
       }

       public int getEmp_id() {
           return emp_id;
       }

       public void setEmp_id(int emp_id) {
           this.emp_id = emp_id;
       }

       public String getLast_name() {
           return last_name;
       }

       public void setLast_name(String last_name) {
           this.last_name = last_name;
       }

       public String getFirst_name() {
           return first_name;
       }

       public void setFirst_name(String first_name) {
           this.first_name = first_name;
       }

       public String getMiddle_initial() {
           return middle_initial;
       }

       public void setMiddle_initial(String middle_initial) {
           this.middle_initial = middle_initial;
       }

       public Date getHire_date() {
           return hire_date;
       }

       public void setHire_date(Date hire_date) {
           this.hire_date = hire_date;
       }

       public int getDept_id() {
           return dept_id;
       }

       public void setDept_id(int dept_id) {
           this.dept_id = dept_id;
       }

       public int getPassword() {
           return password;
       }

       public void setPassword(int password) {
           this.password = password;
       }

       public String getAdmin() {
           return admin;
       }

       public void setAdmin(String admin) {
           this.admin = admin;
       }

       public int getPassattempt() {
           return passattempt;
       }

       public void setPassattempt(int passattempt) {
           this.passattempt = passattempt;
       }

       public boolean isAuthenticated() {
           if (this.password > 0) {
               if (this.password == this.getPassattempt()) {
                   return true;
               } else {
                   setMsg("Member not authenticated");
               }
           }
           return false;
       }
   }
   ```
4. employeeDB.java

   ```
   package business;

   import javax.persistence.NoResultException;
   import org.hibernate.Query;
   import org.hibernate.Session;
   import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;

   /**
    *
    * @author noah
    */
   public class EmployeeDB {
       public static Employee getEmployee(int emp_id) {
           SessionFactory sessionFactory = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory();
           Session session = null;
           Employee e = null;
           try {
               String qS ="from Employee e where e.emp_id = :emp_id";
               session = sessionFactory.openSession();
               Query q = session.createQuery(qS);
               q.setParameter("emp_id", emp_id);
               e = (Employee)q.uniqueResult();

          } catch (NoResultException ex) {
               return null;
           } finally {
               session.close();
           }
           return e;
       }

       public static Employee getEmployee(String empid) {
           throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of                 
            generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
       }
   }
   ```
5. memberScreen.jsp

   ```
   <%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
   <%@taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
   <!DOCTYPE HTML>
    <html>
       <head>
           <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
           <title>Member Welcome</title>
          <style>
               table.member-details{
                   border-collapse: collapse;
               }
               table.member-details td, table.member-details th{
                   padding: 6px;
                   border: 1px solid #999;
               }
           </style>
       </head>
       <c:if test="${!e.authenticated}">
           <script type="text/javascript">
               window.location = "/ClubDB";
           </script>
       </c:if>
       <c:if test="${e.authenticated}">
       <body>
           <h1>Club member Data</h1>
           <form id="memupdate" action="MemberUpdate" method="post">
               <table class="member-details">
               <tr>uu
                   <td>Member ID:</td>
                   <td><input type="text" id="memid" name="memid"
                              value="${e.empid}" readonly="true"></td>
               </tr>
               <tr>
                   <td>Last Name:</td>
                   <td><input type="text" id="lastname" name="lastname" 
                              value="${e.lastname}" ></td>
               </tr>
               <tr>
                   <td>First Name:</td>
                   <td><input type="text" id="firstname" name="firstname" 
                              value="${e.firstname}" ></td>
               </tr>
               <tr>
                   <td>Middle Nm:</td>
                   <td><input type="text" id="middlename" name="middlename" 
                              value="${e.middlename}" ></td>
               </tr>
               <tr>
                   <td>Status:</td>
                   <td><input type="text" id="status" name="status" 
                              value="${m.status}" readonly="true" ></td>
               <tr>
               <tr>
                   <td>Member Date:</td>
                   <td><input type="text" id="memdt" name="memdt" 
                              value="${m.memdtS}" readonly="true" ></td>
               </tr>
               <tr>
                   <td>Password:</td>
                   <td><input type="password" id="psswd" name="psswd" 
                              value="${m.password}" size="22"></td>
               </tr>
               <tr>
                   <td></td>
                   <td><input type="submit" value="Update Member data"></td>
               </tr>
               </table>
           </form>
           <br>
           ${msg}
            <hr>
            <br>View Transaction History From:<br>
               <form action="ShowPurchases" method="post" >
                   <table>
                       <tr>
                           <td>Month:</td><td><input type="text" name="month" 
                                                     id="month" value=""></td>
                           <td>Day:</td><td><input type="text" name="day" 
                                                   id="day" value=""></td>
                           <td>Year:</td><td><input type="text" name="year" 
                                                    id="year" value=""></td>
                       </tr>
                   </table><br>
                  <input  type="submit" value="View Transactions">
               </form> <br>
            <br><br>
            <a href="/ClubDB">Back to the Login Screen</a>
          </body>
       </c:if>
   </html>
   ```

   6. hibernate xml file

      ```
      <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
      <web-app version="3.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"                 
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"         
      xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee 
      http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-        
      iiapp_3_1.xsd">
      <servlet>
          <servlet-name>LogonServlet</servlet-name>
          <servlet-class>servlets.LogonServlet</servlet-class>
      </servlet>
      <servlet-mapping>
          <servlet-name>LogonServlet</servlet-name>
          <url-pattern>/Logon</url-pattern>
      </servlet-mapping>
      <session-config>
          <session-timeout>
              30
          </session-timeout>
      </session-config>
      <welcome-file-list>
          <welcome-file>Logon.jsp</welcome-file>
      </welcome-file-list>
      ```

Comment: I only read the code of your servlet. It doesn't override any of the HttpServlet methods. So it just declares a new method that no one will ever call. Read the javadoc: https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServlet.html. The use your debugger. Or at the very least add println() statements in the code to know what is executed.

Comment: your form says action="Logon" method="post" hence your dopost method should be available in servlet for serving....

Comment: @Shoaeb thank you for your help. I am very new to hibernate so, I apologize, I am having trouble understanding a lot of this. What changes are you suggesting that I make?

Comment: @INoahGuy this has **nothing** to do with Hibernate. Your **servlet** must override doPost. Read my comment again. Read the javadoc of HttpServlet.

Comment: @JBNizet I updated logonservlet.java in the question, it was hidden in an editor fold so I forgot to copy it. Is this the kind of override you meant? I read the javadoc and thought I had already done that, but i could be misunderstanding you. thanks for your help.

Comment: @Shoaeb could you please explain what you think I should do to get this application to work?

Comment: @JBNizet Do you have any idea what the issue is if it is unrelated to overriding doPost?

Comment: for starters you can override the dopost method in your servlet and check if your control goes over there...